# Ubuntu 20.04 suspend reverses scrolling, changes scroll and touchpad speed

Tags: 20.04, suspend, touchpad, scrolling

Recently whenever ubuntu comes out of suspend, the scroll and touchpad speed are higher, touchpad acceleration is turned on and scrolling is reversed.

I've tried resetting my settings with `dconf reset -f /`, I've tried solutions for similar problems on this forum where I created a dconf file with the appropriate settings, nothing has worked so far.

Are there other thing I can try?
Thanks in advance.